# js to force executing just :after or :before but not both

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple html slider

```
 <div class="range-handle" style="left: 188.276px;">100,000</div>
```

When page is loaded I can see this code in firebug like this
[image]

On a page this looks like 
< 100,000 >

I want to intercept users click on both arrows (left and right).

```
 document.querySelector('.range-handle', ':before').addEventListener('click', leftArrow)
 document.querySelector('.range-handle', ':after').addEventListener('click', rightArrow)
```

This partially works, since I always get execution of both actions, no matter which arrow I click. First before event is handled and then after.

> Having above code in mind how can force executing just one event depending which arrow is
>   clicked?

Comment: As far as i know before and after pseudo elements are not in the real dom but they're in shadow dom. So I think your event listener is listening the '.range-handle' element not the pseudo elements thats why both actions are called. That's just my opinion though not exactly sure.

Comment: You can reach what you want with absolute positioned 2 spans inside '.range-handle' element instead of pseudo elements.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot listen for events on pseudo elements, without hacky solutions...

The simplest solution would be to wrap your *arrows* in extra elements:

```
<div class="range-arrow-left"></div>
<div class="range-handle"></div>
<div class="range-arrow-right"></div>
```

Another solution, which would introduce some more javascript:

```
const rangeHandle = document.querySelector('.range-handle')
const rangeArrowSize = 20

function determineArrow(e) {
  cons isLeft  = e.pageX < rangeArrowSize
  cons isRight = e.pageX > rangeHandle.offsetWidth - rangeArrowSize

  if (isLeft) leftArrow()
  else if (isRight) rightArrow()
}

rangeHandle.addEventListener('click', determineArrow)
```

*Untested!*